# Unable to locate package node-legacy

Tags: linux, node.js

$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package node-legacy

please suggest the solution for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-cache search <part of package name your searching for>
```

or search for it on : https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages